# Is it possible to listen to Search Dialog UI Events?

Tags: android, search

I would like to be able to detect when a user types a key in the Search Dialog. I plan on using this to hook in to custom suggestion functionality.

Note: The built-in Search Manager custom suggestions functionality won't work for me because I need to customize the layout of the suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

No, sorry, the global search dialog is not extensible by your code.

Comment: I'm not referring to the global search dialog. I'm referring to the SearchDialog I've instantiated in my own Activity by registering the Intent Filter android.intent.action.SEARCH.

Comment: For example, Can I get a reference to that SearchDialog (or its' parent) so I can set the Event Listener?

Comment: @m2green: If it is your own search activity, then you can do whatever you want. If it is the system search dialog, I know of no way for you to access it -- I'm not even sure it is executing in your process.

Comment: I just ended up avoiding the SearchDialog altogether. It was easy enough to create my own search UI, the the benefit of much more flexibility.

Comment: I guess the SearchDialog is really useful for simple search and/or if you want to expose your App Search to the Global Search.

Comment: @m2green: Agreed. If you want to do anything more than simple keyword search of your own app, you're better served rolling your own UI for it, whether as a separate activity or dialog or whatever.